# SQL- Fetching values with multiple values in 1 column

Tags: sql, relational-division

Hey I've been learning SQL and got stuck on one question. Let's say the database looks like this:

I want to retrieve all of the countries that have a poor AND average rating. In this case, it will only return Brazil and Chile.

| Country | Rating |
| --- | --- |
| Brazil | Good |
| Brazil | Average |
| Brazil | Poor |
| Chile | Poor |
| Chile | Average |
| Chile | Good |
| Argentina | Average |
| Peru | Poor |
| Peru | Outstanding |

I've tried were conditions, IN conditions but it just returns me everything that contains either poor or average.

thanks!

Comment: Not able to see your tables

Comment: child is having outstanding rating also. Brazil is having  good rating also. not understanding your question

Comment: To be a bit more specific, I want to get the country names the have poor and average in rating. In this case, it would be only Brazil and Chile. The coding that I've tried returns all countries that have either Poor or Average.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IIUC, you are looking for

```
SELECT Country FROM your_table
WHERE Rating in ('Poor','Average')
GROUP BY Country 
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT Rating)=2
```

Comment: Tried this one and it would return Brazil, Chile, Argentina and Peru. I would like only to return Brazil and Chile because they are the only ones who contain average and poor as a review.

Comment: This will not return `Argentina` and `peru` for the sample data provided above. Did you really tried this? @Albert

Comment: [Check this Link for Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=c24a2d91cd2244f687afa5d0bbf85d41) @Albert